# Determine a value, where quadratic equation will generate the perfect square

Tags: quadratics, diophantine-equations

In order to find RSA factors ($pq = N$), we have to solve a quadratic equation $x^2+Bx+C=y^2$, where:

- $x_1 < x_2$,
- $x_1, x_2$ and $y_1, y_2$ are (positive) integer numbers,
- $x_1$ is the smallest possible value of $x$ under given conditions,
- we know $B$, $C$, $x_2$ and $y_2$ up front,
- $x_1$ will return us values of $p$ and $q$, while $x_2$ returns us $N$
  and $1$.

We are searching for a procedure, that would reveal $x_1$ value. Procedure must not include a factorization of any value, that would result in $p$ and/or $q$ as factors.

Example:
$$B=1070637348586356278941580589136$$
$$C=1308129990806270450432723124908$$
$$x_2 = 71641520761751435455133616475131771759770154088777081500862$$

What is the $x_1$ value of the above example? What is the procedure to calculate $x_1$ value (without factorization to $p$ and/or $q$ as a part of procedure)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can complete the square to get a [Pell equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation).

Comment: all  that matters is that $A=1.$ Take $z = x + \frac{B}{2}$   Then $z^2 + C -   \frac{B^2}{4}  = y^2  .$   Take $E =     \frac{B^2}{4} - C$   At which point you have $z^2 - y^2 = E. $  As $E$  is divisible by 4,  any factorization  $(z-y)(z+y) = E$  with both factors even gives integer $z,y$ The trivial pair is $ z+y = E/2 \; , \; \; \;   z-y = 2.$  Since $E = 4 pq$  with large primes   $p<q,$  the other choice is $z+y = 2q,  \; \; \; z-y = 2p.$ Or, you know, negatives....then  $x = z - \frac{B}{2}$

Comment: In order to calculate $x$, do you have to know $p$ and $q$ or not? If yes, is there any other method to get $x$, since factors are hard to get in large (RSA) values. Thanks.

Comment: you do need to be able to factor $\frac{B^2}{4} - C.$  That is,  knowing the smaller  $x$ value I wrote tells you how to factor it.

Comment: I factored $E$  first, in gp-pari. It did it quickly, which surprised me when I realized how large $E$  was.

Comment: Understood, thanks. In that case we are looking alternative way to calculate $x_1$ without knowing $q$ and $p$ first. Would Pell's equation work? If helpful, $x_2$ can be calculated from $N$.

Comment: There is no shortcut for factoring.  There is no fast RSA  factoring

Comment: The point is to find shortcut for factoring. I posted one possible way to do that here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4646887

Answer (score 1):

Sure,
$$x =  22551047929025780409738729886$$

$$x = 71641520761751435455133616475131771759770154088777081500862$$